# If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a strictly increasing discontinuous function, can $f([0,1])$ be a subset of $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

If $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a strictly increasing discontinuous function, can $f([0,1])$ be a subset of $\Bbb Q$?

**Attempt:** Since $f$ is a discontinuous strictly increasing function, this means that :

> $1.~ \forall a \in [0,1]: \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x)$ exist
>
> $2.~$ There can be no removable discontinuity. So, if $f$ is discontinuous at a point $a :~\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f(x) \ne\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x)$
>
> $3.~$ There can be only a countable number of discontinuities.

Since there can only be a countable number of discontinuities, and $[0,1]$ is uncountable, $f$ must be continuous on an uncountable number of points. Thus, $f$ must traverse an interval by being continuous at these points and hence, cannot be a subset of rationals because each interval contains uncountable irrationals.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: $f$ doesn't have to be discontinuous. As long as it is strictly increasing, $f([0,1])$ can't be a subset of $\Bbb Q$, by the argument in @Integrand's answer. (What is a "discontinuous function" anyway? Do you just mean that it is not everywhere continuous?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a naive thought but here goes: since $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$, if $x<y$, $f(x)<f(y)$. In other words, $f$ is injective. But then we couldn't have $f([0,1])\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ because $|\mathbb{Q}|<|[0,1]|$.

Comment: I think you meant: since f is strictly increasing

Comment: A function can't be "strictly increasing at a point"!

Comment: @TonyK I think a reasonable definition can be provided that $f$ is not strictly increasing at a point if it is not strictly increasing in any neighborhood of such point.

Comment: @TonyK: there is a definition of increasing at a point. Let $f$ be defined in some neighborhood of $c$. Then $f$ is said to be increasing at $c$ if there is a neighborhood $I$ of $c$ such that $x\in I, x<c\implies f(x) \leq f(c) $ and $x\in I, x>c\implies f(x) \geq f(c) $. The strict inequality lead to definition of strictly increasing.

Comment: @TonyK: the key result is that if a function is increasing at every point of an interval then it is increasing in entire interval (proof requires completeness of reals).

Comment: @rubikscube09: the definition of increasing at a point can not be based on increasing in a neighborhood.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it seems that we have provided the same definition - I essentially meant that we say $f$ is increasing at $x$ if there is a neighborhood of $x$ on which $f$ is increasing. Is there a problem with this definition?

Comment: @rubikscube09: yes the definition in your last comment does not match mine. The function $f(x) =(x/2)+x^2\sin(1/x),f(0)=0$ is strictly increasing at $0$ as per definition in my comment as $f'(0)>0$ but in every neighborhood of $0$ the derivative $f'$ takes negative sign as well so that there is no neighborhood of $0$ in which $f$ increases.